# Integrator with Voltage on IN+ and measuring Vout and V-?

Tags: operational-amplifier, transfer-function, integrator

I know the ideal integrator topology and output equation. But - what is the affect of connecting a supply at the positive input (instead of GND)? How can that be calculated mathematically for NODE1 and NODE2?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEVWkW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Initial condition can be found (assuming VC3 = 0), and  equate the two inputs for the op-amp not saturated to get the current through C3.

Comment: P.S. Without looking up the datasheet for the OP97, I'm pretty sure it's not going to work very well with a +1V supply and a +1V input. Also, the bottom one should presumably be negative. The way you've drawn it, the chip doesn't have any supply voltage.

Comment: The supplies are +/- 15V and the +IN is +5V. I just updated it.

Comment: Better, but the bottom 15V supply should be flipped. It still has no supply voltage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the superposition theorem you can calculate Vout (node 2) as a result of Vn1 (node 1) and V1=1V:

**Vout=V1 + (V1-Vn1)/s*R1C3**

For V1=0 this simplifies to the well-known MILLER integrator formula
Vout=-Vn1/S*R1C3.

Comment: What is the `s`?

Comment: It is common practice to use for "jw" the symbol"s".

Answer (score 1):

The result would be a ramp on the output, which will eventually saturate at the plus or minus rail, depending on the sign of the difference between V1 and node 1.  As for node equations, all the current through R1 goes right into C3, charging it, with no means of discharging it. Since
$$ i= - C \frac{dV}{dt} $$
Then 
$$ V=\frac{-1}{C}\int i \:    dt $$

i would just be (Vnode1 - V1)/R1

Comment: I just wanted to look at that piece of circuit first. Both nodes are connected to other parts in a larger circuit